# How can I force maven to package my project against 1.5?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to compile a maven project, the source code uses Generics and other featuers of Java 1.5, thus causing my build to fail

In my `POM.xml` I have configured the build configuration against 1.5 for the source and target properties, but this doesn't solve my issue

Is my `POM.xml` correct, or am I missing something?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>MyClass</name>
    <groupId>uk.co.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyClass</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
      <finalName>MyClass</finalName>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.5</source>
            <target>1.5</target>
            <descriptors>
              <descriptor>src/main/resources/dist.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
            <archive>
              <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sun-repo-2</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Output when attemtping to build

```
generics are not supported in -1.3 (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You configured the assembly-plugin with some information about source/target but to configure the compiling you need to configure the [compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) in the correct way.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.5</source>
    <target>1.5</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Update:**
This should be combined with maven-enforcer-plugin to force really using of JDK 1.5 instead of only using source/target option of the javac.

Answer (score 25):

You have to set some properties to compile with java 1.5

```
<properties>
    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin configuration -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: This will not configure the compiler plugin. It will define some properties only.

Comment: Some properties used by the compiler plugin : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#source

Comment: This is nice, I never thought of that, although it should be obvious. +1

Comment: This solution is much better in the long run, since it does not hardcore and force the plugin version.